# Is there a way to globally override requests' timeout setting?

Tags: python, python-requests

We have usages of the requests library littered throughout our project. Recently we came across a bug in one of our destinations where it froze mid transaction, and decided to just hold the connection open.

Naturally, our application followed suit.

Is there a environment variable, or some other way to set the timeout? Even if it's significant (say, 30 seconds) it should be enough to stop the entire works from stopping because of one service. If possible, it should be global so that I don't have to find every single use, and so that people can't forget to add it in the future.

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3341

Comment: You can always extend the class!

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim that solution does not address the last sentence.

Comment: You could patch in the __init__.py of your project. Then it'll be used all the time, even for future code. I patch logging this way.

Comment: @wyx , the link is now https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3341

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, looking at the code, there is no possibility to set a global default value. I was kinda surprised by that, as I would expect that to be quite common use case. If you start a feature request, please let me know (e.g. in comments to this post).

The reason for that is that methods like `get(...)`, `post(...)`, etc are all just thin wrappers over `Session.request(...)` method (`requests.get(...)` creates new one-shot session, just for a single request). That method takes `timeout` as argument, and does not inspect `Session` internals for a value if there is no timeout argument, so you always have to put it there manually, like [2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043170/2ps) proposed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41296110/1219585).

Sources:

> Revised [on master on 31.08.2020](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/02eb5a2cd34d36548ebb08528c73ca66c2a398d9/requests/sessions.py). Line numbers have changed, but methods stayed the same. The answer stays the same.

- [`requests/__init__.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/__init__.py) - import API to package scope, to provide `requests.get(...)`-like utilities
- [`requests.api`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/api.py) - API module that is imported in point above; usess one-shot sessions
- [`requests.sessions`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/sessions.py) - `Session` implementation

  - [line 337](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/sessions.py#L337) starts `Session` class
  - [line 463](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/sessions.py#L463) starts `request(...)` method
  - [line 526](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/sessions.py#L526) actually uses `timeout` parameter
  - [line 534](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/sessions.py#L534) start `get(...)` method

> PS. See [this pull request](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/5230). Disclaimer: it's mine.

Answer (score 51):

The simplest way is to ["shim" the session's `request` function](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2011#issuecomment-490050252):

```py
import requests
import functools

s = requests.Session()
s.request = functools.partial(s.request, timeout=3)

# now all get, post, head etc requests should timeout after 3 seconds
# following will fail
s.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/6')

# we can still pass higher timeout when needed
# following will succeed
s.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/6', timeout=7)
```

Answer (score 16):

Instead you could inherit the requests.Session class and rewrite `request` function, like this.

```
HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30

class TimeoutRequestsSession(requests.Session):
    def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('timeout', HTTP_TIMEOUT)
        return super(TimeoutRequestsSession, self).request(*args, **kwargs)

session = TimeoutRequestsSession()
session.get('https://www.google.com') # connection timeout is default 30s
```

Comment: This proposal would require me to find every single use, and somehow make sure people don't forget about it in the future. As such it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: To make it simple. You could do like this.  `requests = TimeoutRequestsSession(); requests.get(...)`

Comment: See [2ps answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41296110/1219585) for details how the timeout can be configured

Answer (score 9):

Two ways to make this happen. It involves some dirty monkey patching. Tested on python 3.6.

Put this somewhere in a file like main.py, an **init**.py or urls.py and make sure it is called.

Option 1: patch the requests method

```
import requests

def request_patch(slf, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Fix called")
    timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', 2)
    return slf.request_orig(*args, **kwargs, timeout=timeout)

setattr(requests.sessions.Session, 'request_orig', requests.sessions.Session.request)
requests.sessions.Session.request = request_patch
```

Option 2: Patch the Session class

```
import requests

class SessionTimeoutFix(requests.Session):

    def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Fix called")
        timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', 2)
        return super().request(*args, **kwargs, timeout=timeout)

requests.sessions.Session = SessionTimeoutFix
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not?:

```
    for method in ("get", "options", "head", "post", "put", "patch", "delete"):
        setattr(
            session,
            method,
            functools.partial(getattr(session, method), timeout=timeout),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it per call with the `timeout` parameter:

```
requests.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=10)
```

The `timeout` parameter specifies the number of seconds or a tuple for (connection timeout, read  timout).  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).

If you want to make this global, the easiest way is to refactor all of the calls into a wrapper class and make sure that everyone is using the wrapper class to call this API endpoint.  I did a quick check of the requests code and did not see the use of a global override for timeout since the default behavior is to wait for data.

Comment: nah, `counter = 1; try: request.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=5); except : counter+=1 ; if counter > My_limit : Nevermind()`